# Filtering rows based off of relation to date column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a good way to filter data based off of the date column (Column I in my actualy spreadsheet).  I can copy the rows and all of that to another sheet just fine, but the date thing is new to me.  Basically I need to know how to filter based on three situations:

1. If the current date is within 3-6 months of the date in Column I;
2. If the current date is within 0-3 months of the date in Column I;
3. If the current date is past the date in Column I.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the DATEDIFF VBA function.  Here is an example:  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DateDiff you can use:

```
Date()
Year()
Month()
Day()
```

Functions to determine this information.